# Spring boot unit testing suggestion.?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I have a controller class and a service class.
Controller has endpoints and service layer has functions performing something specific (inserting, loading a file and counting lines, updating, etc).

Now what I want to know is, should I unit test an endpoint(controllers) as a whole or individual functions present in the service layer? I've really been confused. Please help.

Comment: Both. Separately.

Comment: Unit testing means isolating and testing units separately. You should have two test cases. If both pass then both should work together.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you should have two test classes-

One for the controller, with the service mocked, testing the controller's functionality.
One for the service, with the dal layer mocked, teating the service

Answer (score 0):

You need two test classes

1. controller class testing
2. service class testing

Controller class test
- This class will test the your endpoints and their functionality. You can achieve this using RequestBuilder and MockMvc. You can mock your service class call.

Service class test
- This class will test your actual business logic (inserting, loading a file and counting lines, updating, etc.). You can mock your repository call and any other calls if there.